# MySQL query problem

Tags: sql, mysql

I have 4 tables

```
Table: Category
    CategoryID (int)
    Name (varchar)
Table: Products
    ProductID (int)
    CategoryID (int)
    Name (varchar)
    Description (text)
Table: Sales
    SalesID (int)
    ProductID (int)
Table: Links
    LinkID (int)
    ProductID (int)
```

Now I need to display data as:

```
CategoryName     Total Products     Total Sales     Total Links
    ABC                5                 12            50
    XYZ               12                 26            10
```

How can I achieve this, may be in single query

Help appreciated

Thanks

Comment: I can see how you would relate `Products`, `Sales`, and `Links`, but what column links `Category` in with these?

Comment: yes, obviously there is a missing link here.

Comment: Edited: I added CategoryID to products table

Comment: @I-M-JM: for reference, [SQL JOINs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29), [GROUP BY](http://www.sql-tutorial.com/sql-group-by-sql-tutorial/) and [aggregate functions](http://www.sql-tutorial.com/sql-aggregate-functions-sql-tutorial/).

Comment: Can you add PK and FK to your tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT c.Name AS "CategoryName", COUNT(p.ProductID) AS "TotalProducts", COUNT(s.SalesID) AS "TotalSales", COUNT(l.LinkID) AS "TotalLinks"
FROM Category c
INNER JOIN Products p ON p.CategoryID = c.CategoryID
INNER JOIN Sales s ON s.ProductID = p.ProductID
INNER JOIN Links l ON l.ProductID = s.ProductID;
```

I don't know how the data looks like but you may need to add a `GROUP BY` somewhere if you have duplicates or an optional `ORDER BY` if you need sorting in any of the columns

Comment: by the way, I replaced inner join to left join, and it helped.